# Simple way to create animations on iOS?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, animation, core-animation

I need to create about 100 animations for an iOS app (UIKit). Is there a simple way to do so without hand-code Core Animation or using video files ( -> that way the app would be huuuge!)
I thought about some utility/tool for creating such scripts & then exporting them to ObjC-code..
Something like adobe flex

Any ideas?

Comment: what kind of animations?

Comment: very simple, like a human skeleton doing some work..

Comment: how long (seconds) would each animation be and what dimensions (in pixels)

Comment: 10-20 secs each. iPhone and iPad screen sizes

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `UIImageView` and set the `animationImages` and `animationDuration`. Then call the method `startAnimating`.

Tutorial-Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCsumlHiEc0

Comment: yes, but the app would still be huge because of that many images. I thought about code-based solution

Comment: this approach is very easy and flexible, a code based solution depends on the kind of animation